# Variable incremented in bash while loop resets to 0 when loop finishes

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I'm writing a bash script that uses a `while` loop to process over the rows outputted from a specific command. I also increment a variable (adding 1) for each row found.

Heres an example of the section of the script in question:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count=0

ls | while read f
do 
  count=$(($count+1))
  echo "Count is at ${count}"
done

echo "Found total of ${count} rows"
```

Basically, it increments the `$count` variable just fine, but then when I print `$count` after the while loop.. its reset to 0..

Example output:

```
Count is at 1
Count is at 2
Count is at 3
Count is at 4
Count is at 5
Found total of 0 rows
```

Any idea why the `$count` would reset after the loops done?

I also tried adding the last echo statement using the `&&` operator on the loop, like so:

```sh
count=0

ls | while read f
do 
  count=$(($count+1))
  echo "Count is at ${count}"
done && echo "Found total of ${count} rows"
```

With no success.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls` in any case; use `for f in *; do` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pipe spawns a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), use a [process substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) instead:

```
while read -r f
do 
  count=$(($count+1))
  echo "Count is at ${count}"
done < <(ls)
```

Also note that you shouldn't [parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

And your example seems to count numbers of files and directories in current directory, which can be done with find and wc:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf "\n" | wc -l
```

or you can avoid `ls` with a for loop and globbing:

```
for f in * .*; do
  [ -e "$f" ] || continue
  count=$((count + 1))
  echo "Count is at ${count}"
done
```

Comment: Note that both of your alternatives include hidden files, which the `ls`-parsing version does not.

Comment: Your first snippet using the `< <()` worked great! thank you. Can you tell me why I had to do that? and just piping it wouldnt work?

Comment: @Justin read the first linked page in the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks @andlrc, the second snippet in that link is exactly what I was looking for!